# Organizar datos de un arreglo en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy trabajando en una base de datos que contiene la información de las notificaciones que son emitidas a los alumnos de una Institución educativa.

Posterior a la ejecución de una consulta `sql` para obtener el detalle de la notificación con el id número `85` obtengo esta información:

```js
let data = [
  {
    idnotificaciones: 85,
    not_fecha: '2019-11-03',
    alu_representante_nombres: 'José', // nombre del representante
    alu_apellidos_nombres: 'Marco',
    not_curso: 'INICIAL 1 B',
    not_tutor: 'Maria',
    idnot_asunto: 77,
    not_asunto: 'Justificar faltas'

  },
  {
    idnotificaciones: 85,
    not_fecha: '2019-11-03',
    alu_representante_nombres: 'José', // nombre del representante
    alu_apellidos_nombres: 'Marco',
    not_curso: 'INICIAL 1 B',
    not_tutor: 'Maria',
    idnot_asunto: 78,
    not_asunto: 'Solucionar asuntos disciplinarios'
  },
  {
    idnotificaciones: 85,
    not_fecha: '2019-11-03',
    alu_representante_nombres: 'José', // nombre del representante
    alu_apellidos_nombres: 'Marco',
    not_curso: 'INICIAL 1 B',
    not_tutor: 'Maria',
    idnot_asunto: 79,
    not_asunto: 'Otros'
  }
]
```

Como se puede observar la información contiene elementos que se repiten, a excepción de los campos `idnot_asunto` y `not_asunto`.

En consecuencia, me interesa organizar la información para que tenga la siguiente estructura:

```js
let data = {
  idnotificaciones: '85',
  not_fecha: '2019-11-03',
  alu_representante_nombres: 'José',
  alu_apellidos_nombres: 'Marco',
  not_curso: 'INICIAL 1 B',
  asunto: [
    {
      idasunto: 1,
      not_asunto: 'Justificar faltas'
    },
    {
      idasunto: 2,
      not_asunto: 'Solucionar asuntos disciplinarios',
    },
    {
      idasunto: 3,
      not_asunto: 'Otros',
    }
  ]
}
```

A continuación adjunto el código utilizado para conseguir el objetivo, creo que no es la forma más eficiente de hacerlo, pero es lo que me a funcionado.

Acudo a esta comunidad a fin de obtener información que permita obtener ideas y conceptos para mejorar las practicas de programación.

```js
let dt = {};
if (data.length > 0) {
  dt.idnotificaciones = data[0].idnotificaciones;
  dt.not_fecha = data[0].not_fecha;
  dt.alu_representante_nombres = data[0].alu_representante_nombres;
  dt.alu_apellidos_nombres = data[0].alu_apellidos_nombres;
  dt.not_curso = data[0].not_curso;
  dt.not_tutor = data[0].not_tutor;
  dt.asunto = [];

  if (data.length >= 1) {
    for (let index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
      dt.asunto[index] = {
        id: data[index].idnot_asunto,
        not_asunto: data[index].not_asunto
      };
    }
  }
}

console.log(dt)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Todo se ve bien, solo el `if(data.length >= 1)` no es mecesario puesto que se valida con el primero.

Para el for puedes usar map retornando un objeto por cada uno solo con las propiedades que necesitas.

```
dt.asunto = data.map((item) => {
    return {
        id: item.idnot_asunto,
        not_asunto: item.not_asunto
    };
});
```

Comment: excelente gracias.